# Using Stored Procedure to output data in Java

Tags: java, mysql, stored-procedures

I've been sitting and googling and messing with my code for a while and have no errors being reported anymore. I can't figure out why only one of my output values work out.

I have a "student" table in my database with the columns, snum, sname, major, level, and age.

Here is my procedure I created:

```
    SELECT student_name = sname, 
    student_major = major, 
    student_level = level, student_age = age 
    FROM student 
    WHERE snum = student_num
```

My parameters are:

`INOUT student_num BIGINT(20)`

`OUT student_name VARCHAR(255)`

`OUT student_major VARCHAR(255)`

`OUT student_level VARCHAR(255)`

`OUT student_age BIGINT(20)`

What I am trying to do with this is have the user input a Student ID number, then I will get the rest of that student's information once I find a Student ID match in the database.

```
    public void procedureGetStudentInfo(String spName) {

    try {
        statement = connection.createStatement();

        //Creating variables to store the output of the procedure
        int id = 0;
        String student_name = "";
        String student_major = "";
        String student_level = "";
        int student_age = 0;

        CallableStatement myCallStmt = connection.prepareCall("{call "+spName+"(?,?,?,?,?)}");
        myCallStmt.setInt(1, student_num);
        myCallStmt.registerOutParameter(1, Types.BIGINT);
        myCallStmt.registerOutParameter(2, Types.VARCHAR);
        myCallStmt.registerOutParameter(3, Types.VARCHAR);
        myCallStmt.registerOutParameter(4, Types.VARCHAR);
        myCallStmt.registerOutParameter(5, Types.BIGINT);
        myCallStmt.execute();

        //Grabbing information from query
        id = myCallStmt.getInt(1);
        student_name = myCallStmt.getString(2);
        student_major = myCallStmt.getString(3);
        student_level = myCallStmt.getString(4);
        student_age = myCallStmt.getInt(5);

        //Outputting information to user
        System.out.println("Student ID: " + id);
        System.out.println("Student Name: " + student_name);
        System.out.println("Student Major: " + student_major);
        System.out.println("Student Level: " + student_level);
        System.out.println("Student Age: " + student_age);

    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The output is:
Student ID: 51135593
Student Name: null
Student Major: null
Student Level: null
Student Age: 0

The ID is set by the user so this was easy. I don't really even need to pull it from the database, but the other 4 values are what I can't get to pull.

If anyone can help me out that would be much appreciated. I want to teach myself SQL and get good at it, but the trivial stuff I'm getting stuck on still.

Answer (score 0):

I think the cause is a little mess with your parameters' indexes. Look:

Parameter 1 should be entered as input parameter:

```
myCallStmt.setInt(1, student_num);
```

So, it should not be registered as an output parameter: For me, this line should be removed:

```
myCallStmt.registerOutParameter(1, Types.BIGINT);
```

(Moreover, parameter `student_num` should be declared as IN in the s.p.)

Comment: When I run the stored procedure after making that adjustment now every value returns null.